# Retrieving a column from mySQL database and passing to array

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

I have previously constructed an array manually, e.g.:

```
<?php
$noupload = array('nick', 'cliff');
?>
```

but now I am trying to populate the array automatically from users in a MySQL database.  So far I have this:

```
<?php
// Make a MySQL Connection
$debug=false;
$conn = mysql_connect("host","user","password"); // your MySQL connection data
$db = mysql_select_db("database");

$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE access LIKE '%listen%'"; 

$result = mysql_query($query) or die(mysql_error());

while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    $listen = "'". $row['login']. "', ";
}
?>
```

`$listen` constructs the user list in the way that I previously entered it manually (I tested this using echo), but I am not sure how to pass this to `$noupload`.  I tried:

`$noupload = array($listen);`

but this didn't work.  I think I'm close and would be grateful for some help over the final hurdle,

Thanks,

Nick

Comment: To confirm - you may get multiple results from your SQL query and you want to create a string array with the 'login' column from each result?

Comment: Also, why have a `SELECT *` if you're only accessing the `login` attribute, you can `SELECT login FROM users WHERE access like "%listen%"`. If you don't need more data then the login field, don't ask the DB for more.

Comment: Thanks, I have set it to SELECT login only.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can declare `$listen` as an array

```
$listen = array();
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($result)) {
    $listen[] = "'". $row['login']. "'";
}
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked great!  I will mark as the answer in a couple of minutes

Comment: I can see you have now edited the line `$listen[] = "'". $row['login']. "'";`  It worked before you edited it.  Should I change it?

Comment: As a side note, use `$listen[] = "'{$row['login']}'";` It saves two unnecessary string concatenations. (`.` operator)

Comment: This makes an array but from your example I think you just want `$listen[] = $row['login'];` ie drop the quotes. It seems you were only adding the quotes to simulate the syntax of declaring an array.

Comment: Yes, the edited version above doesn't work, but the original did work, with the line `$listen[] = $row['login'];`.

Comment: @Nick, do not edit other people's answers, except to change spelling errors or to help clarify how it reads. Code changes should be suggested, but it is up to the answerer whether they want to incorporate that change, not you. They can give you permission to make the change, but please don't do it without that.

Comment: OK, sure.  I'm clear on the procedure now.  But, just to confirm, the answer above as it stands doesn't work.  It did work before it was edited by the answerer